# Ruby for loop only using last value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop

Going a bit mad here.

```
@sport = Sport.find(params[:sport])
@activities = Activity.where("sport_id = ?", @sport)
```

@activites outputs fine with the below:

```
<% @activities.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.id %>
<% end %>
```

showing 2 values as predicted.

My problem is, when I write (in the controller):

```
for a in @activities
  @facilities = Facility.where("id = ?", a.facility_id)
end
```

My output for:

```
<% @facilities.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.id %>
<% end %>
```

only returns 1 value. It should show 2 values as each of the above activities belong to different facilities. I think it is either something to do with the for loop OR when I define  @facilities it is only registering one value.

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: Don't use `for`, use `each` or `map`, depending on your goal. The latter are idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-assigning `@facilities` on each iteration of the loop.  I think you want something more like:

```
@facilities = []
for a in @activities
  @facilities << Facility.find(a.facility_id)
end
```

This might be better written as

```
@facilities = @activities.map {|a| Facility.find(a.facility_id) }
```

But, preferably, you've defined an association for :facility

```
@facilities = @activities.map {|a| a.facility}
```

Comment: Ahhhh THATS what I was looking for. I knew the problem but no solution. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

You're right:

> ... when I define @facilities it is only registering one value.

For each iteration of this loop:

```
for a in @activities
  @facilities = Facility.where("id = ?", a.facility_id)
end
```

you're clobbering the previous value in `@facilities` and replacing it with a new one. At the end of the loop, only the final value of `Facility.where("id = ?", a.facility_id)` is retained.

Instead, you could use `map` to obtain an array of all of the facilities:

```
@facilities = @activites.map do |a|
  Facility.where("id = ?", a.facility_id)
end
```

Then continue in your view as you did before:

```
<% @facilities.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.id %>
<% end %>
```